# Getting Scrollable Resultsets from Oracle DB

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, resultset

We are working in our team pretty tight up with an `Oracle` DB server using `jdbc`. In one of our changes, I'm calling a Stored Procedure which returns me two different `ResultSets`. At first my implementation assumed default Scroll-ability.
After that failed, I looked it up in the Internet.

Everything I could read about it said basically the same thing: use `prepareStatement` or `prepareCall` methods with the appropriate `TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE` and `CONCUR_READ_ONLY`. None of these worked.

The Stored Procedure I use, again, return me two different result sets and they are extracted through a `(ResultSet) rs.getObject("name")`. Generally in examples, their ResultSet are coming back instantly from a `.executeQuery`.
My Question is,  **Do the Scrollablility/Updatability types in the `prepareCall` methods affecting these sort of ResultSets? if so, how do I get them**?

I know that the JDBC driver can degrade my request for ScrollableResultSet. **How can I tell if my ResultSet was degraded?**

On that note, **Why aren't ResultSets scrollable by default? What are the best practices and what is "the cost" of their flexibility?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle, a cursor is a forward-only structure.  All the database knows how to do is fetch the next row (well, technically the next n rows).  In order to make a ResultSet seem scrollable, you rely on the JDBC driver.

The JDBC driver has two basic approaches to making ResultSet seem scrollable.  The first is to save the entire result set in memory as you fetch data just in case you want to go backwards.  Functionally, that works but it has potentially catastrophic results on performance and scalability when a query potentially returns a fair amount of data.  The first time some piece of code starts chewing up GB of RAM on app servers because a query returned thousands of rows that included a bunch of long comment fields, that JDBC driver will get rightly pilloried as a resource hog.

The more common approach is to for the driver to add a key to the query and to use that key to manage the data the driver caches.  So, for example, the driver might keep the last 1000 rows in memory in their entirety but only cache the key for the earlier rows so it can go back and re-fetch that data later.  That's more complicated to code but it also requires that the ResultSet has a unique key.  Normally, that's done by trying to add a `ROWID` to the query.  That's why, for example, the Oracle JDBC driver specifies that a scrollable or updatable ResultSet [cannot use a `SELECT *`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/java.102/b14355/resltset.htm#CIHEJHJI) but can use `SELECT alias.*`-- the latter makes it possible for the driver to potentially be able to blindly add a `ROWID` column to the query.

A ResultSet coming from a stored procedure, however, is completely opaque to the driver-- it has no way of getting the query that was used to open the ResultSet so it has no way to add an additional key column or to go back and fetch the data again.  If the driver wanted to make the ResultSet scrollable, it would have to go back to caching the entire ResultSet in memory.  Technically, that is entirely possible to do but very few drivers will do so since it tends to lead to performance problems.  It's much safer to downgrade the ResultSet.  Most of the time, the application is in a better position to figure out whether it is reasonable to cache the entire ResultSet because you know it is only ever going to return a small amount of data or to be able to go back and fetch rows again by their natural key.

You can use the `getType()` and `getConcurrency()` methods on your ResultSet to determine whether your ResultSet has been downgraded by the driver.

Comment: I am really happy for the Oracle API attached in your link. So far I was looking in the wrong places for such extensive answer.

However, regarding the degrade, `getType()` and `getConcurrency() ` just allow me the query the ResultSet properties. I am more interested about checking a flag that indicate that such degrade was performed. That's because I am not sure that I am instructing `JDBC` for `scrollable Resultset` correctly. However I think can query on from here with the docs from oracle.

Vielen Dank